# How to persist the border radius of a container on a background-color hover change?

Tags: html, css

I have a drop-down list that has a `border-radius` on the bottom corners, and I want to change the color of the `li` items when you hover on them. However, when you hover on the last list item, the `background-color` covers the border radius. How would I keep the `border-radius` of the parent container when I hover on the last `li` item?

```css
.menu {
  max-width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.menu .menu-item {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.menu .menu-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.menu .menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
    <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
    <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
    <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
    <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just put `border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;` on `.menu .menu-item:last-child` as well

Comment: Oh, duh. Thank you very much. I was thinking about `background-clip` or something.

Comment: or overflow:hidden on the menu item

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu {
  max-width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.menu .menu-item {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.menu .menu-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.menu .menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
  <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
  <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
  <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
  <li class="menu-item">A Menu Item Text</li>
</ul>
```

this will keep the formatting even with hovering over the last menu option